try to use database using Spring JDBC but its show noclassdeffounderror
error msg i got Error :-NoClassDefFoundError
12:19:07.250 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@24b1d79b
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractBeanFactory.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:176)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.<init>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:201)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:638)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at jdbc.mainioc.main(mainioc.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.metrics.ApplicationStartup
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 11 more

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class mainioc 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        
        ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Appmeta.xml");
    JdbcTemplate temp= (JdbcTemplate) ctx.getBean("dataS");
    //insert query 
    String query="insert into employee(id,name,salary) values(?,?,?)";
                
    //fire query 
    int result=temp.update(query,3,"ram",14578);
    System.out.println("record inserted"+ result );
}
}



i try to add dependency spring starter


  org.springframework.boot
  spring-boot-starter-web
  2.3.3.RELEASE

```
myentity class
package com.spjdbc.entity;



public class student 
{
 private String id;
 private String Sname;
 private String Srollno;

 @Override
public String toString() 
 {
    return "student [id=" + id + ", Sname=" + Sname + ", Srollno=" + Srollno + "]";
}
public String getId() 
{
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) 
{
    this.id = id;
}
public String getSname() 
{
    return Sname;
}
public void setSname(String sname) 
{
    Sname = sname;
}
public String getSrollno() 
{
    return Srollno;
}
public void setSrollno(String srollno) 
{
    Srollno = srollno;
}
 

}

meta file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
<bean id="DataS" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb"/>
<property name="username" value="root"/>
<property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcB" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
<property name="dataSource" ref="DataS"/>
</bean>

</beans>

test file 
package com.spjdbc.ioc;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;


public class iocmain {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    ApplicationContext  cont= new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com/spjdbc/ioc/BeanConf.class");
    JdbcTemplate temp= cont.getBean(JdbcTemplate.class);
    String query="insert into student(id,Sname,Srollno) values(?,?,?)";
    int result = temp.update(query,1,"ram",24001);
    System.out.println("intert the value" +result);

    }

}

Annotation
package com.spjdbc.ioc;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
@Configuration
public class BeanConf 
{
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() 
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(); 
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");
        return dataSource;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() 
    {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }
    
}

how can i resolve the issue Bean not accessesible itry both the form XML aand Annotation but cant work

Mixing incompatible versions of different jars of the spring framework. Don't do that. Make sure the versions match.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

You need to add dependencies for Spring Data JPA as well as the database connector you want to use (MySQL) to your pom.xml.:
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

These are taken from https://start.spring.io/

after adding these dependencies error remain same no changes
